# Find records where its @OneToMany relation is not empty

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'd like to select all `Users` where its `photos` property is not empty. In other words, "select users where photos is not empty".

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from "typeorm"
import { User } from "./User"
​
@Entity()
export class Photo {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
​
    @Column()
    url: string
​
    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.photos)
    user: User
}


import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from "typeorm"
import { Photo } from "./Photo"
​
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
​
    @Column()
    name: string
​
    @OneToMany(() => Photo, (photo) => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[]
}
```

Is this possible in `typeorm`, or is `SQL` the only way to go? Thank you.

Comment: I checked the typeorm repo and it seems someone recently committed for a `whereExists` feature similar to `whereHas` we see in other ORMs. You could check this thread for more info https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2815

Comment: Thanks Istiyak. I'll keep an eye on your suggestion and see if it solves the issue I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QueryBuilder` and `leftJoinAndSelect`. The query would be as simple as:

```
const users = await userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.photos', 'photos')
    .where('photos.id IS NOT NULL')
    .getRawMany();
```

Edit: If you want the output to contain an array of photos for each user, just replace `getRawMany` with `getMany`.

```
const users = await userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.photos', 'photos')
    .where('photos.id IS NOT NULL')
    .getMany();
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but the output is not correct. Why: if a user has N photos, I would expect the output to be 1 User object with the photos property containing N photos. Instead, I receive an array of N elements (one for each photo), each one containing the user properties + photo properties merged.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention about the format of the output you expect. Anyways, just replace `getRawMany` with `getMany` and you would get the desired result. See edit.

Comment: Yup. That did it. Thanks Rahul.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using TypeORM QueryBuilder.

There are two joining options in their [docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#joining-relations) leftJoinAndSelect and innerJoinAndSelect

> The difference between LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN is that INNER JOIN
> won't return a user if it does not have any photos. LEFT JOIN will
> return you the user even if it doesn't have photos.

So, if you want to return only those users who have atleast one photo you can use  .innerJoinAndSelect().

```
const queryBuilder = this.repository.createQueryBuilder("users");

queryBuilder
  .where(...)
  .innerJoinAndSelect("users.photos", "photos", [Optional where], [Optional where variables object])
  .orderBy(order)
  .skip(skip)
  .take(take);

 const { entities } = await queryBuilder.getRawAndEntities();
```